# Add dots on canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I want to add text which is hidden by dots after "Generate Color Blind Image" button is pressed. Now my following code gives me a dotted image but my problem is I want the image must be 600*600 pixels but it's giving me 539*539 images after download by clicking "Download" button. Also, dots are not completely shown in the entire downloaded image.

Download button is not working in Stackoverflow but it's working properly in JsFiddle and other expected platforms: https://jsfiddle.net/0y13Lpan/

My Downloaded Image is this:

[image]

**539*539 (Which I want 600*600) size and dots are not completely visible in the entire image.**

**Code:**

```js
var dotRatio = 20; // Default dot ratio, you can change this value as desired

function generateColorBlindImage() {
  // Get the container div element
  var containerElement = document.getElementById('container');
  // Reduce the opacity of the text
  document.getElementById('text').style.opacity = 0.2; /* Set the opacity to 20% */
  // Show the dotted pattern
  document.querySelector('.dotted').style.display = 'block';
  // Generate the color blind image (same as previous code)
  // ...
}

function downloadImage() {
  // Get the container div element
  var containerElement = document.getElementById('container');
  // Show the dotted pattern before capturing the image
  document.querySelector('.dotted').style.display = 'block';
  // Convert the container div to a canvas
  html2canvas(containerElement, {width: 600, height: 600}).then(function(canvas) {
    // Draw the dotted pattern on the canvas with the specified dot ratio
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var patternSize = dotRatio;
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += patternSize) {
      for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += patternSize) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
    // Create a temporary link element
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.download = 'color_blind_image.png';
    // Append the link to the body and click it to trigger download
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    // Remove the link from the body after download
    document.body.removeChild(link);
 

    // Reset the container size and hide the dotted pattern after download
    containerElement.style.width = '';
    containerElement.style.height = '';
    document.querySelector('.dotted').style.display = 'none';
  }, 500); // Wait for 500 milliseconds (0.5 seconds) before capturing the image
}
```

```css
 #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
      background-color: lightgray;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    /* Style for the text */
    #text {
      font-size: 48px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: red;
      opacity: 0.5; /* Set the opacity to 50% */
    }

    /* Style for the dotted pattern */
    .dotted {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: none; /* Hide the dotted pattern by default */
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <!-- Text to be displayed -->
    <div id="text">LOVE</div>
    <!-- Dotted pattern to surround the text -->
    <div class="dotted"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button to generate color blind image -->
  <button onclick="generateColorBlindImage()">Generate Color Blind Image</button>

  <!-- Button to download the generated image -->
  <button onclick="downloadImage()">Download Image</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I downloaded the image from your link (https://jsfiddle.net/0y13Lpan/). The image size is 600 x 600px. Maybe... there are some wrong css setting in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Canvas not the right size**

After looking at the html2canvas [doc](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration), I think the root cause is this: "scale: The scale to use for rendering. Defaults to the browser's device pixel ratio." For me, somehow my browser defaults to 1.5 scale.

I took reference from this [github issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1904).

Adapting from the answers posted, changing

```
html2canvas(containerElement, {width: 600, height: 600}).then(function(canvas)
```

to

```
html2canvas(containerElement, {scale: 1}).then(function(canvas)
```

solves the scaling issue as it fixes the scale at 1.

**2. Dots not filling up the canvas**

Next, for the issue of the dots not filling up the whole canvas,

```
for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += patternSize) {
  for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += patternSize)
```

it is an issue of inequality `<` not drawing the last row/column of dots, so I changed the above code to the code below:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x += patternSize) {
  for (var y = 0; y <= canvas.height; y += patternSize) {
```

I have updated the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n80r6ujc/